# Cannot access local Sinatra server from another computer on same network

Tags: ruby, web-services, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra server that I run through textmate but I can't access from another computer on the same network.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p327 and Sinatra 1.4.1 on a Mac OS 10.8.3. Firewall is disabled.

I tested the same scenario on different networks and computers.

The computer responds to simple pings but when I try to telnet port 4567 I can't establish a connection.

Comment: Why are you using telnet? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Sinatra is a web framework. Try with a browser.

Comment: Does not work with a browser either

Comment: Just to make sure : did you include the port number at the end of the ip address? Something like : your.ip.address:4567

Comment: @marco-fiset telnet is (or was anyway) a standard way to test for open ports on a remote system. It was an excellent diagnostic step.

Comment: Good question, was having the same issue.   @marco-fiset telnet is usually the first and best option available for something like this which is what I did to confirm the port was not available.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There was a [recent commit to Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/commit/0f9a959253bdf0c39422ffb9b60278df46ef0248) that changed the default listen address to `localhost` from `0.0.0.0` in development mode due to security concerns.

In order to explicitly allow access from the network, you need to either run your app in another mode (e.g. production), or set the [`bind` option](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__server_hostname_or_ip_address) to `0.0.0.0`.

You can do this from the command line using the built in server using the `-o` option:

```
$ ./my_sinatra_file.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: That recent commit was recent at the time of @matt's answer, but here it is a year later and the default binding is buried in the Sinatra docs and not mentioned in the the Getting Started. grrr...

Comment: You can also set it directly in your app using `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'`

Comment: Yet Another Way To Do It: `MyApp.run! :port => 3000, :bind => '0.0.0.0'` in your config.ru, then either `rackup` or `ruby config.ru`

Comment: You'll also need the `-o` switch if you use a config.ru file and start your app with `rackup`  - i.e. `rackup -o 0.0.0.0` - See answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899777/cant-launch-simple-sinatra-app-using-rackup-and-jruby-no-response-from-web-ser)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the sinatra server is not listening on only the localhost (127.0.0.1) ip address.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry, I'm a complete noob :)

Comment: Read the Sinatra help, or run your server with the `-h` flag. It tells how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I'm chiming in with a little extra information that may help people like me banging their heads against the wall.

I'm on a Windows machine, not a Mac, and I had to open the port I was using (default for Sinatra is 4567) to the public (even though I'm on a university network).

To do this in Windows 10:

1. Hit the windows key
2. Search for firewall and hit enter
3. Go to advanced settings
4. Click on inbound rules in the top left
5. Click on new rule in the top right
6. Click the port option
7. Enter your port (probably 4567 for Sinatra)
8. Next
9. And now pick from domain/private/public.

Now another thing to consider is who can access your web server. If you want anyone, then pick public. I don't know for sure (and would love other's input) how to get only devices on the same public network to connect. You can also allow specific IPs through, but for that I suggest doing some research on your own.