# Ruby Sinatra Webservice running on localhost:4567 but not on IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, sinatra, webrick

I have a ruby(using sinatra) webservice on windows 7 32 bit OS. Its running on port 4567.
Its working fine when I use **localhost:4567** but when I replace localhost with the local ip of my machine say, **192.168.103.99:4567** it doesn't work, and fails to connect.
I have already disabled the firewall, by-pass proxy and added port 4567 to exception, still no luck.

What might be the issue ?

Comment: Check localhost is bound to IPV4 localhost 127.0.0.1 and not an IPV6 localhost.  Also, what web server are you using?  Mongrel, Thin, Webrick, Passenger?

Comment: How to check that ? Its WEBrick 1.3.1

Comment: ping localhost and see what ip address is resolved.  To bind webrick to a specific ip, see this documentation: http://smyck.net/2007/03/11/how-to-bind-webrick-to-any-ip-address/

Comment: on pinging localhost its returning reply from something like ::1: which I think is ipv4 ?

Comment: ::1 is not ipv4, it's ipv6.

Comment: Oh, so may be that's the issue, should I bind it to ipv4 ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30894/discussion-between-mcfinnigan-and-smilepleeeaz)

Comment: sure..waiting for you there. :)

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118971/cannot-access-sinatra-app-through-the-local-network) that helped me once.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Following worked for me.

`ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 27):

When using the built-in server through the `run! if app_file == $0` check, [Sinatra's doc](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) explains that `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` is required to make the interface available outside the `localhost` layer.

It is not required to use a custom IP address or a reverse DNS (mydomain.com…): `'0.0.0.0'` is the legit value [expected by Sinatra](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/8b39bbdd2d260e7de31571d5591c0c6299ba955b/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1863), which will be interpreted correctly.

Therefore, a minimal, self-contained Sinatra application made available on all interfaces, not only `localhost`, would be:

```rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

  get '/' do
    'Hello World'
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

Answer (score 11):

To set server hostname or IP-address use [sinatra setting](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) *bind* like

```
set :bind, '192.168.103.99'
```

Answer (score 1):

this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require "dbi"

set :bind, '192.168.200.185'
get '/' do
    'hello word'
end
```

Comment: This works, but needs a bit of explanation for the answer.