# Can't get azure Ubuntu VM to show the installed website

Tags: ruby, azure, ubuntu-18.04

I am new to Microsoft Azure. I am trying to set up a ruby software. Once installed it opens a website page for login. I am using Linux VM with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have completed the installation procedure and its ready to be seen on the browser. But when I hit the browser, it says "This site can’t be reached". I don't get it why I am not able to access the website. My software loads the website on port "4567".

I have already add "Inbound Ports" and added ports 80,443, 4567. But still no luck.

Please help.

Comment: Do you check if the ruby software is in the running state and still listen to the port 4567?

Comment: yes, I didn't make any changes in its port. The same software is working on my localhost and I am able to view the website there. But it's not working on the azure server. I have this port enabled but still no luck. I am not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: There is no difference between the azure server and the localhost if the system is the same. You just need to check if the firewall blocks the port and if the software works well. There may be two NSGs associated with the subnet and the nic. So you need to add rules to both of them to expose the port.

Comment: I didn't get you @CharlesXu. How do I check firewall blocks, NSGs etc? I just check `nohut.out` file it says "== Someone is already performing on port 4567!". Is there any way I can restart ruby and try again? I don't think azure would want to add any restriction in the panel and besides, I have already activated the above mentioned ports. Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: I don't work on ruby. So there is no idea for it. But the error means the port 4567 is already in use by another program. So maybe you can use another port for your software. For NSG, you need to provide more message. A screenshot about the VM -> networking is more helpful.

Comment: ok. I have uploaded the list of inbound links. Is that what you want to see?

Comment: No, not the rules, is the whole configuration. For example, if there is an NSG associated with the subnet. Additional, you need to check your software first as I said in the above comment.

Comment: I have not installed subnet. let me check the rest

Comment: The subnet is something of the vnet that the VM in, so if the VM exists, the subnet exists.

Comment: Okay. Here is the NSG page. I couldn't locate the other terms. But I tried to run the application on other ports, and on each port, the application is throwing the same error. Also, I found that application maybe trying to run on `http://localhost:<port>`. I tried to change the command to run the application on the server but on my localhost it is running and not on the azure server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue while looking at the internet for random issues links. I am posting this here, maybe it helps someone else. I found this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20879984/3825106) and it worked for me. My website was actually running for localhost whereas it should run on from the browser on Azure server so by doing this `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` is required to make the interface available outside the localhost layer.