# Accessing local Ruby Sinatra App with Nexus 7

Tags: ruby, sinatra, localhost, nexus

I'm trying to access my Sinatra app that's running on a Mac with a Nexus 7. My Mac network settings are:

http://oi43.tinypic.com/depto9.jpg

and my Nexus 7 settings are:

http://oi44.tinypic.com/o7nixd.jpg

The Mac and Nexus device are on the same Wi-fi network. When I try to access a specific web app page on the Nexus

```
http://192.168.1.193:3000/kiosk
```

I get the default Sinatra "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" page.

When I run this same url on my Mac, I get the correct web app page. I've looked at this solution:
[Cannot access sinatra app through the local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118971/cannot-access-sinatra-app-through-the-local-network)

```
 ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

however, I need to use

```
foreman start
```

to run this specific app. Does anyone have a solution for accessing a Sinatra app on the Nexus 7 using forman?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using foreman, you should have a `Procfile` that states what are you starting and how. It should probably contain line like this:

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
```

so you can try by replacing it with your line:

```
web:    ruby app.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

or if you plan to continue using thin, you can pass additional parameters

```
web:    bundle exec thin start -p $PORT --address 0.0.0.0
```