# Can't launch simple Sinatra app using rackup and jRuby (no response from web server)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby, rackup

I've got a Sinatra "hello world" app that I am trying to run using jRuby. It works when I run the app, but not when I run rackup. Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Here's the app, in a file 'app.rb':

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

configure do
  set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
end

get '/' do
  'Boo!'
end
```

I can run this using `bundle exec ruby app.rb` and it works fine:

```
jonea@centos7andy[~/andy/sinatra_sand_jruby]%: bundle exec ruby app.rb
[2015-01-12 10:36:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-12 10:36:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-12-09) [java]
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2015-01-12 10:36:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=31654 port=4567
```

Here is my config.ru to call the above program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'
require './app'

run Sinatra::Application
```

If I run this, it appears to work, but I can't access the server using a web browser:

```
jonea@centos7andy[~/andy/sinatra_sand_jruby]%: bundle exec rackup -p4567
[2015-01-12 10:29:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-01-12 10:29:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-12-09) [java]
[2015-01-12 10:29:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=31553 port=4567
```

I note the suspicious lack of "Sinatra has taken the stage..."

Comment: Where is your config.ru file?

Comment: @Sirl33tname -- in the same directory as the app.rb file. And that's where I'm running both commands from.

Comment: Now do this trick: wrap it in a Docker container and try to troubleshoot. :facepalm: Solution is the same as the top answer here, except in that context, it's `CMD ["rackup", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is hardly sufficient to explain what is going on, but I can make it work if in config.ru I replace

```
run Sinatra::Application
```

with

```
Sinatra::Application.run!
```

In fact, knowing that makes me even more confused. Some sort of bug in Rack?

Comment: And here is the opposite: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/759

Answer (score 37):

When you run the Ruby file directly (or when you add `Sinatra.run!` to the `config.ru` file) Sinatra runs its own server. In this case the call to set :bind, '0.0.0.0' will take effect. When you run through `rackup` this setting is ignored.

The default host that [rackup listens to is `localhost`](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/514), so the server will only be available through the same machine, you won’t be able to access it from other machines. To access it through other machines set the `--host` option:

```
bundle exec rackup -p4567 --host 0.0.0.0
```

(Note the output of `rackup -h` for the current version says the default host is 0.0.0.0, but this is out of date and has been [fixed in master](https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/076711a837cda3f07889cab05cb89964ce2314f0).)

Comment: That's a nice theory -- but it doesn't explain a failure under jRuby explicitly. I should have explained that this works fine under MSI Ruby.

Comment: @AndyJones what versions of rack are you using under MRI and JRuby? If you have an older version in MRI it would explain the difference. The change to only listen to localhost is only in rack 1.6+.

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3, Rack 1.6.0 I'm afraid.  I will retest under MSI tomorrow to make sure this still works, though, thanks.

Comment: I have the `bind 0.0.0.0` in my `configure do` so I'm not using it.

Comment: The `configure do` and the `:bind` option only affect the server that Sinatra uses itself when you run the file directly (or use `Sinatra.run!`). If you want to set the host when using `rackup` you need to use the `--host` option to it. It’s the rack version of the Sinatra `:bind` setting.

Comment: Matt, that appears not to be the case; see my own answer to this question. I can change the config.ru and make it work without adding a `--host` parameter or fiddling with the `bind` option.  The problem is that I don't know WHY this works, and my config.ru no longer looks anything like the Sinatra documentation...

Comment: Matt: also, if that were true, it would presumably be true also for MSI ruby? Cos it isn't.

Comment: `Sinatra::Application.run!` starts the _Sinatra_ built-in server. When you have this line in your `config.ru` you tell Sinatra to start its own server before the rack one. But you don’t actually specify an app for rack to start, so when you exit the server rack will try and continue but not find anything to run. Check your output when you do that – do you get an error like `missing run or map statement` after you stop it?

Comment: You can also set the option in the `config.ru` if want to avoid needing it from the command line – add `#\ --host 0.0.0.0` at the top. (See https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/%28tutorial%29-rackup-howto.)

Comment: Matt, there is no error like that, and this doesn't happen in MSI Ruby, so -- how can I put this politely?  -- your explanation of events turns out not to be true.

Comment: So you’re saying that if you have a `config.ru` that _doesn’t_ have a `run Sinatra::Application` line (or a different `run x`x` or `map xxx`) line you don’t get an error when you run `rackup`? You definitely should get an error in this case, as you are not telling rack what app to run.

Comment: Also, are you trying to connect from a browser running on the same machine or from a different one? My explanation is only for connecting from a different machine, which suggested itself because you are only setting the host when running the server via Sinatra. If you can’t connect from the same machine there may be some other problem as well. If so you’ll likely need to provide more information.

Comment: MSI Ruby: `run Sinatra::Application` works.  jRuby: doesn't, but `Sinatra::Application.run!` does. Yes, I'm running the Sinatra on a headless machine somewhere in our stacks, and testing it from my desktop.

Comment: What about `bundle exec rackup -p4567 --host 0.0.0.0` on JRuby?

Comment: what about it?  Please re-read the question. I have a set of circumstances that work and a set that do not, and neither appear to involve the host/bind definition. The fact that I can get this to work without changing the host/bind definition pretty much demonstrates that this has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit sarcastic. Are you testing MRI and JRuby from exactly the same directory on the server, so that they are using the same `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? My suspicion is that you are somehow testing MRI and JRuby with different versions of Rack, so that the new default (listening to localhost) is only effecting JRuby, whilst MRI is using an older version of Rack that listens on 0.0.0.0. Also: you should be able to check where the app is listening with something like `netsat`.

Comment: Note there are _two_ host settings, one for Sinatra, and one for Rack. When you use `ruby app.rb` or when you have `Sinatra::Application.run!` in your `config.ru` you are using the `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` setting, which is the Sinatra one. When you use `run Sinatra::Application` in your `config.ru` you need to use the rack setting, which is `--host 0.0.0.0`. Note that having `Sinatra::Application.run!` in the `config.ru` isn’t using rack to start the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
#config.ru
require "./app.rb"

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :port, 9292 #set your port!
Sinatra::Application.run!
```

try this code and type `rackup`

Then you can get the results you want.

Comment: As explained by matt, this is *not* the right solution. If you use `Sinatra::Application.run!` you don't need `rackup` at all.

Comment: `set :bind, '0.0.0.0'` works and is necessary for both `ruby config.ru` and `rackup`. It also requires `Sinatra::Application.run!`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly similar situation. 
But the difference is that, my Jruby + Sinatra rackup app is finally starts responding.

But it takes lots of time, sometimes it starts responding 5 minutes after app start.
I found out, that after app start port is not listened for some period time.

If we make netstat -an it will not show our app port.
Actually I don't know the reason of such behavior, but I'll dig for it.

Comment: Having a similar problem, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: After upgrade to jruby-9000 it has gone. No idea what was the root of problem

Comment: Thanks. In my case, this behavior only happened on DigitalOcean (not my mac, in or outside docker), and on the droplet in question I couldn't even get jruby-9000 to install (it just hung), so I built a new droplet on the latest ubuntu and installed docker myself, and it worked. It did not simply work to build a new droplet using the stock ubuntu+docker app. I have no idea whether this problem was a docker version problem, an Ubuntu version problem, or a DigitalOcean problem or some combination.

Comment: Actually, it turned out to be blocking on insufficient entropy available to `/dev/random` which can be ["fixed" by using an insecure source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html). This seems particularly relevant to DigitalOcean droplets for some reason.