# How to connect to Stripe server from device?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm using Stripe and a sinatra and json enabled ruby script to charge credit cards on iOS.  The charge works on the iPhone 6 simulator but not an iPad mini device running 9.3.5.

I tried changing the baseURL string to my ip address so the app can connect to the server `htpp://192.168.1.11` but it still gets the error. I even tried something like `http://192.168.1.11:4567`. How can I get the physical app to connect to the server?

```
//original baseURL for the app
enum Constants {
...
static let baseURLString = "http://localhost:4567"
...
}
```

iPhone 6 Simulator

[image]

iPad mini version 9.3.5

[image]

The original tutorial used Swift 4, iOS 11, Xcode 9 but I changed the deployment target and podfile to iOS9.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RWPuppies' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Cards'


end
```

Ruby script

```
#1
require 'sinatra'
require 'stripe'
require 'json'

#2
Stripe.api_key = 'YOUR_TEST_SECRET_KEY'

#3
get '/' do
status 200
return "RWPuppies back end has been set up correctly"
end

 #4
post '/charge' do
#5
payload = params
if request.content_type.include? 'application/json' and params.empty?
payload = indifferent_params(JSON.parse(request.body.read))
end

begin
#6
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
  :amount => payload[:amount],
  :currency => payload[:currency],
  :source => payload[:token],
  :description => payload[:description]
 )
#7
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
status 402
return "Error creating charge: #{e.message}"
end
#8
status 200
return "Charge successfully created"

end
```

**Solved:**

1. Opened my Projects info.plist file and Added a Key called NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary. Added a Subkey called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its value to YES 
   [How do I load an HTTP URL with App Transport Security enabled in iOS 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9)
2. set baseURLString to `http://192.168.1.11:4567`
3. Ran the script from the terminal as `ruby web.rb -o 0.0.0.0`
   [Cannot access local Sinatra server from another computer on same network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685528/cannot-access-local-sinatra-server-from-another-computer-on-same-network/40568040)

Comment: Are you missing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I added the plsit update to allow arbitrary loads and added my ip address to the base URL and now the app gets an unsupported URL error. When i keep the original `http://localhost:4567` I get the same could not connect to server error.

Comment: Solved: This helped. Thank you